# How to open a new activity which has list of item at specific position in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

When I select a particular item from list of my current activity it should open a new activity which will have a list of time(hrs) from 0 to 24 hrs.

The problem is it should display the present hour at top (based on current system time)

i.e. Second activity will have list from 0 to 24 and will display from 5hrs and ahead if current system time is 4.30 hrs. But if I scroll up it should display the whole list starting from 0 till 24hrs.

Sorry if i forgot anything to mention as I'm new to android programming. Help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: It should scroll to that position based on current time. I don't want to hardcore to a specific position like mentioned in that post

Comment: Making that solution generic should be simple. Just pass the row that you want to scroll to based on the current time.